# Pick up next message from Queue after request has been processed?

Tags: wso2-esb

My endpoint in ESB only allows a max of 3 connections at a time, how can I make sure that none of my incoming requests are lost.

Even if I add a queue how can I restrict the flow from the queue?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: I am using Message Sampling Processor is there a way in which I can control the pace with which messages are being picked.
What I want is that the next 3 message gets picked only after the first three messages have been processed by my backend service.